# How to change menu labels for different user roles?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I would like to change menu labels for different user roles. For example: admin can create different content types so the default label - create content is okay, but for a standard user who can create just one type content I would like to have something like 'Post Article'. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a separate menu for each role. Each menu could have the individual menu items named differently, as needed. You could then use the block system to control which menus get displayed to which roles.